# Bootstrap Datepicker Startdate from attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I know you can set startdate when initialising your datepickers within the config settings. I havn't found a way to add an attribute within the html input to do this.

The way I got around this was like so.

```
$('.date-picker').each(function () {
    if($(this).attr("startdate") !== undefined) {
        $(this).datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy", weekStart: 0, autoclose: true, startDate: $(this).attr("startdate") });
    }
    else {
        $(this).datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy", weekStart: 0, autoclose: true });
    }
});
```

I write this out in Razor with the following

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeDate, new { @class = "date-picker", @data_date = "12-02-2012", @startdate = "12-04-2012" })
```

Could any one suggest the right way?

This is working for me which is cool for now, it adds a disabled css class on anything before the date 12-04-2012.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use .data() rather than .attr()

```
<input type="text" class="date_picker" data-start-date="2012-01-01">
```

and then

```
$('.date-picker').each(function () {
  var config = { format: "dd/mm/yyyy", weekStart: 0, autoclose: true  };
  if ($(this).data("startDate") != undefined) {
    config.startDate = $(this).data("startDate");
  }
  $(this).datepicker(config);  
});
```