# Disable all days except any two date in a month bootstrap date picker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Dev,

I have requirements such as "**Need to disable all the dates except 1st & 16th date every month**".

My customer doesn't want to select the rest of the dates at any time. I have tried to achieve that in a lot of ways but I was not able to find a solution.

Here, While I google everyone suggested to use "**beforeShowDay**" and check the date as 1 & 16 then return true. But I don't want to go by that solution. Because my application datetimepicker() uses common code.

So I want to achieve the solution by using data attributes. Like "**data-date-days-of-week-disabled="[0,6]**" I have disabled Saturday & Sunday by using this method.

Could anyone help me write data attribute logic for my scenario?

I tried, **data-date-days-disabled=[2,3,4,5,6]** up to 30 except 1 & 16. But it's not working.

[image]

Here I have disabled the Saturday & Sunday by using **data-date-days-of-week-disabled="[0,6]"**

Like wise I want to disable the date 2 to 15 and 16 to 30 / 31. Meaning I want to enable 1st date & 16th date of each month.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker revenueStartDate" data-min-view="2" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy"  data-date-days-of-week-disabled="[0,6]"   >
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" size="16" type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" value="#dateformat(now(),'mm-dd-yyyy')#">
    <div class="input-group-append"> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-th mdi mdi-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+datepicker+disable+dates+except+data-attribute+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263038/bootstrap-datepicker-startdate-from-attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332583/3814721

Comment: @mplungjan , Please read my question well. I wish to resolve that by using data attributes in input tag itself. Not through JS code.

Comment: @Kannan.P share the code which you applied for `data-date-days-of-week-disabled`

Comment: @Kannan.P You have jQuery tagged and no example code. So it is hard to find a dupe that fits

Comment: I have updated my source code with screen please check it and confirm @mmushtaq